# Проблема с изменением цвета пунктов списка в asp:DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, цвета

Нужно изменить цвет пунктов в элементе `asp:DropDownList`.

Сделал так:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            for (int i = 0; i < myData.Length; i++)
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(i + 1 + ") " + myData[i].ItemArray[0]);
                DropDownList2.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
            }
```

Сам `DropDownList`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Список формируется без ошибок, но цвет текста не меняется. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myData.Length; i++)
{
   DropDownList2.Items.Add(i + 1 + ") " + myData[i].ItemArray[0]);
   DropDownList2.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "color:red !important;");
}
```

В опере, microsoft edge, хроме и яндекс браузере это работает. Однако, FireFox не отображает цвета. Возможно, проблема кроется в кэше браузера. Его очистка не помогла решить проблему.